# How to improve Leverage browser caching

Tags: php, performance, caching

I have developed my site fully in PHP and now when i test speed of my site it slow.In google site speed test "https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftrainsrunningstatus.net%2F" this shows "Leverage browser caching".
Please sugguest me how to improve my speed with this.

Comment: I also need to improve the subpages of my website - [https://trainsrunningstatus.net/running-status](https://trainsrunningstatus.net/running-status)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a different thing except this htaccess code.My your own expiration list according to your files.

```
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```